# beautiful soup not fetching all html

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new in scrapping and python, I have written a code to scrape web page,

[This is the link](http://www.hl.co.uk/funds/fund-discounts,-prices--and--factsheets/search-results/a). Using the code given below. But in the response it doesn't have all the html. The data in middle of page is not fetched. I have tried both lxml and html.parser but no difference.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.hl.co.uk/funds/fund-discounts,-prices--and--factsheets/search-results/a'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

I don't know the reason probably I am missing any key point or anything.

Comment: Probably the data is loaded via JS. You can use `selenium` to fetch the data

Comment: are you sure, I know selenium but i think it's slow as compared to bs4

Comment: Are some of the links under "funds" not being fetched? Or some other data from the page?

Comment: yes links under "funds" are not being fetched

Comment: @AyyanKhan you mean links under "funds" menu?

Comment: @Kumar yes, I want to scrape those links

Comment: Those links are getting populated using xhr requests. These are the URLs. http://www.hl.co.uk/ajax/menus/16508,
http://www.hl.co.uk/ajax/menus/16512,
http://www.hl.co.uk/ajax/menus/16516,
http://www.hl.co.uk/ajax/menus/16526 you can use network tab in developer console to see them.

Comment: @Kumar I tried scrapy, They appear in scrapy html fetch, Is scrapy have ability to do that?

Comment: @Ayyan Khan You can try regex to extract the desired links from html. Then create new request using scrapy on those links.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.hl.co.uk/funds/fund-discounts,-prices--and--factsheets/search-results/a'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
for fund in soup.select("ul[class='list-unstyled list-indent'] > li > a"):
    print(fund.attrs['title'])
```

The result will be

```
Aberdeen Asia Pacific and Japan Equity (Class I) Accumulation
Aberdeen Asia Pacific and Japan Equity Accumulation Inclusive
Aberdeen Asia Pacific Equity (Class I) Accumulation
Aberdeen Asia Pacific Equity (Class I) Income
.
.
.
AXA WF Framlington Robotech (Class F) Accumulation
AXA WF Framlington Robotech (Class F) Income
AXA WF Framlington UK (Class L) Accumulation
AXA WF Global Strategic Bonds (Class I H) Accumulation
```